# iOS file i/o best practice

Tags: ios, file, io, plist, nsdictionary

I am writing a iOS app that contains an array of NSDictionary objects these objects can be added/removed and edited by the user. The array is stored in a plist and loaded at runtime. I am wondering what the best practice would be on when to store the data into the plist i.e. should I do it every time the array changes or only when the app is terminated or goes in the background?

Comment: Sounds like you are reimplementing Core Data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing it only when the app is terminated or goes to the background would be fine.  If you have very large data, you may want to do it periodically because you only get so much time to "wrap things up" when the application is about to terminate.  But will small data, it is just fine to write on terminate or when entering background.

Comment: Also, you are not "reimplementing Core Data".  Core Data is one way of having persistent data, but plists, NSCoding, and UserDefaults can work as well in the right situations.  Not every persistent data solution needs Core Data.

Comment: OK, not reimplementing all of Core Data. Just the Atomic Data Store.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to have more information about the nature of your app, but I would save on background/terminiation.  It seems inefficient to be saving every couple seconds if there isn't a need for it.

I would save as often as necessary for your app to function properly, no more and no less.